# tabular in-memory vs multidimensional and molap-mode

Tags: ssas, cube, tabular, in-memory, rolap

I have a question regarding the ssas-models tabular and multidimensional cube.
I've read that both models can work in a real-time-mode (direct query mode & rolap).

My questions concerns the tabular model in in-memory-cache-mode and the multidimensional model in molap-mode. How recent is the data there? Can I define myself how often the data gets refreshed or how is this managed?

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, in regards to real-time mode, ROLAP is indeed as real-time as the data source it is utilizing.  Therefore, if it is accessing a data warehouse that performs daily ETL, it is only as up to date as the warehouse.  SSAS Tabular direct query mode is only applicable with a SQL Server data source (currently).

The main purpose of ROLAP or direct query mode is to yes, allow for real-time (if that is a reporting requirement) but mainly to put the processing requirements on the data source server rather than the Analysis Services server.

Second, in regards to Tabular in-memory and MOLAP multidimensional modes, yes, you define the frequency via a scheduled SSIS package or XMLA script.